# arduino and pass-by-reference

Tags: c, arduino, pass-by-reference

here is my code (basically all from the starter kit's 2nd exercise):

```
int switchState=0;
int flag=0;
void change(int &i){
 if (i==0)
  i=1;
 else
  i=0; 
}

void setup(){
pinMode(3,OUTPUT);  
pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
pinMode(2,INPUT);
flag=0;
}

void loop(){
 switchState=digitalRead(2);
 if (switchState==HIGH)
   change(flag);

 if (flag==0)
 {
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
 }
 else{
  digitalWrite(3, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);

  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  delay(100);
 }
}
```

i want to get the "click" of the button to switch from blinking leds to the steady one and viceversa, but i only can get the first button click.

why the "change" function works only once?

Comment: If you pass by reference, then this language is not C. Did you mean C++?

Comment: I think its a debounce issue, probably code it with checking the key press after delays or design proper circuitry

Comment: You need to detect a LOW to HIGH transition on the button to change the flag.  Keep track of the previous state of the input so you can tell.

Comment: i think it's a problem of "threading" or sort of... i need a separate thread which only check the button status